# How to access HttpContent content by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm adding data to an HTTP POST request in an ASP.Net WebForm using `MultipartFormDataContent.Add()`. However, in the Web API application that's receiving the POSTed data, I'm not clear on how to extract these data by the names I gave them.

In the API I'm using `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()` and getting the `Contents` into a `Collection<HttpContent>` collection, but there does not appear to be any way to access the content except via an index.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you say web API, do you mean a ajax call, or  webmethod of that page? Remember, webmethods don't do a full page postback. So in that web mehod, you can't reference any of the controls on that form (becuase the page not been posted back to the server). And you can't even use ViewState either. You have to use session() to persit those values.  But, you want to post the webmethod api you have for that page - but as a general rule, such web methods don't involve a page post back, and thus the state of that page and controls on that page don't exist for that web method.

Comment: On the WebForm's submit button (code-behind) I've written this code:

            Models.Request req = new Models.Request();

            req.FirstName = tbxFirstName.Text;
            req.LastName = tbxLastName.Text;

            // Get options that were checked; convert them to List<string>
            List<string> options = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items
                                    where item.Selected == true
                                    select item.Value).ToList();

...

Comment: // Now attach them to the model
            req.Options = options;

            // Now add the files that were uploaded...
            ctx.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "data");

Notice that I'm specifying "data" as the name of the data I'm sending. Also, just below this code is where I'm doing an HTTP POST to my API.

Now, in the API, I'm getting the POST and all the data comes across as expected. I'm using this code to get the request content:

...

Comment: MultipartMemoryStreamProvider msp = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
            Collection<HttpContent> contents = msp.Contents;

The issue is, in order to read the json data from the "contents" variable, I'm having to use 

contents[index].ReadStringAsync().Result

Where "index" is the position of the data (here it would be 0 but in the real world I'll have several json documents).